# Capistrano gateway used only for some server but not all

Tags: capistrano

I am using capistrano to deploy and I need to access during the process some servers that are behind a gateway, and some that do not use this gateway.

How can I specify which server uses a gateway (and which gateway) and which one does not?

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem before and have never found a "correct" solution.  I imagine it's out there but as a workaround you could potentially use the [multistage](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) functionality.

Let's say you have two servers you want to run your Cap task but only one requires a gateway.  Put them in different stages where one has the gateway setting and the other does not.

The downside is you have to run your task twice - once with each stage setting but this is a fairly trivial cost.